# Nicematrix errors with aastex631

Tags: tables, nicematrix, aastex

### Summary of Error

I am trying to use [nicematrix](https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix) in a [AASTeX v6.3.1](https://journals.aas.org/aastex-package-for-manuscript-preparation/) LaTeX document. However, I get several errors such as "Missing number, treated as zero."

**Any suggestions on how I can use nicematrix with AAStex?**

#### Tex file using AASTex

```latex
\documentclass[ApJL,twocolumn]{aastex631}
\usepackage{aas_macros}
% \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
    \hline
    Writer & \Block[l]{}{year\\ of birth} \\
    \hline
    Hugo & 1802 \\
    Balzac & 1799 \\
    \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

##### Error log summary

> ‪main.tex, 18‬
> Package array Error: Illegal pream-token ([): `c' used.

> ‪main.tex, 23‬
> Missing number, treated as zero.

> ‪main.tex, 23‬
> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

> ‪main.tex, 23‬
> Missing number, treated as zero.

> ‪main.tex, 23‬
> Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

#### Tex file without AASTex

```latex
% \documentclass[ApJL,twocolumn]{aastex631}
% \usepackage{aas_macros}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
    \hline
    Writer & \Block[l]{}{year\\ of birth} \\
    \hline
    Hugo & 1802 \\
    Balzac & 1799 \\
    \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

#### Compiled doc (without AASTex)

[image: compiled doc]

Comment: The [AASTeX author guidelines](https://journals.aas.org/aastexguide/#tables)  explicitly mention "There is support in the AASTeX package for tables via two mechanisms: LATEX’s standard table environment, and the deluxetable environment, which allows for the formatting of lengthy tabular material. Tables may be marked up using either mechanism, although use of deluxetable is preferred. "

Comment: Yeah, @leandriis! I noticed that, but was hoping Id still be able to use `nicematrix`.

Comment: @AviVajpeyi Unfortunately, `aastex631` redefines `array` in a way that makes it impossible for `nicematrix` to work.

Comment: (I'm the author of `nicematrix`). I will try to see if it's possible to make `nicematrix` comptatible with `aasteex631`  (even though AASTeX recommand to use deluxetable).

Comment: Yay! thanks @F.Pantigny! `nicematrix` is awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 6.2 of 2021-09-09) is compatible with the class `aastex631`.

More precisely, that version is compatible with the class `revtex-4.1` which is used by `aastex631` (even though `revtex-4.1` is obsolete and should be replaced by `revtex-4.2`). The class `revtex-4.1` redefines `{array}` (of the eponymous package) and `nicematrix` (in the latest version) adds code to come back to the standard definition of `array` before using `{array}`.

However, there are, in fact, some lines of code to add in the preamble when using `nicematrix` with `aastex631`:

```
\BeforeBegin{NiceTabular}{\let\begin\BeginEnvironment\let\end\EndEnvironment}
\BeforeBegin{NiceArray}{\let\begin\BeginEnvironment}
\BeforeBegin{NiceMatrix}{\let\begin\BeginEnvironment}
```

Here is an example.

```
\documentclass[ApJL,twocolumn]{aastex631}
% \usepackage{aas_macros}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nicematrix} % at least version 6.2 (2021-09-09)


\BeforeBegin{NiceTabular}{\let\begin\BeginEnvironment\let\end\EndEnvironment}
\BeforeBegin{NiceArray}{\let\begin\BeginEnvironment}
\BeforeBegin{NiceMatrix}{\let\begin\BeginEnvironment}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
    \hline
    Writer & \Block[l]{}{year\\ of birth} \\
    \hline
    Hugo & 1802 \\
    Balzac & 1799 \\
    \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Remark if you use Overleaf: Overleaf has not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`